# Single vs multiple ViewModels in Android Jetpack

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I have this situation where view renders data from Android ViewModel(s) but functionally they are distinct. One could be showing, say, some financial data and the other one sports-related.

One approach would be (assuming only 2 here but could be lot more)

```
Fragment -> View 1 ->   |                      | Repository for 1
                        |  --> View Model -->  |
            View 2 ->   |                      | Repository for 2
            ...
```

Other one being

```
Fragment -> View 1 ->   |  --> View Model 1 --> | Repository for 1
                        
            View 2 ->   |  --> View Model 2 --> | Repository for 2
            ...
```

I prefer the second one because, at least, we will have individual viewModelScopes (based on the tag used internally by ViewModel). Being supervisor jobs coroutines launched for one view will not impact (in case of errors) ones launched for others but still, we will have clear code organization.

Is there any argument to chose the first approach (having a single Android ViewModel)?

Comment: Answer also depends on if both fragments appear at the same time.

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid in my case, multiple fragments wont appear together